# Total (Sum?) with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, sumifs

I have my clients on one sheet and their bought items.
On the sheet where I have my client names, I want to have their total.

My code will only "sum" the first cell it encounters that matches the vlookup, it will not add all the cells together matching the vlookup:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP([@Customer],Details!B2:F10,5,FALSE))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that I get a total of a Customers bought products.
My table looks like this:

```
Client|Product|Price  
------|-------|-----  
A     |Salade |2  
B     |Koffee |3.5  
A     |Apple  |0.5
```

What I want is that I can get sum of A (beeing 2.5), but now I only get the value "2".
I had no luck with SumIF.

Comment: VLOOKUP is only supposed to give one result. Use SUMIF or for more sophisticated use DSUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=sumproduct((A2:A4="A")*(C2:C4))

That is the formula you basically want.  you will need to replace the "A" with your cell reference that holds what you are looking for.  Adjust the range of A2:A4 and C2:C4 to match your range.  Ensure they are equal in length.

You can read more on SUMPRODUCT [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) and [here](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html)

Based on your VLOOKUP formula I would guess your formula would look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DETAILS!B2:B10=[@Customer])*(DETAILS!F2:F10))
```

Alternatively you could use the SUMIF formula:

```
=SUMIF(DETAILS!B2:B10,[@Customer],DETAILS!F2:F10)
```

[SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) will check the b2:b10 range for cells matching @Customer's cell value.  When a match is found, it will add the corresponding value in the F2:F10 range.  Of the two methods it is the preferred method.

If you wind up needing multiple conditions, SUMPRODUCT can be adjusted or you can use SUMIFS.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCHT(VLOOKUP([@Customer],Details!B2:F10,5,FALSE)) gives me the same values as SUM

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((DETAILS!B2:B10=[@Customer])*(DETAILS!F2:F10)) did the trick!
Thank you!

Comment: trailing spaces will affect things  Ensure you have no trailing/leading spaces in @Customer.  It has to be an exact match to B2:B10.   Same goes for B2:B10

Comment: Yes, it would, I just notice you substituted in your whole VLOOKUP.  Good luck with the rest!